# Fiddler Event Log font operations

Tags: c, event-log, fiddler

I'd like to make the **Fiddler Event Log** more readable.

Right now I use `####` lines so I can check the different responses and self-made actions.

The best thing would be the use of font operations like color, **bold** or *italic*.

I could just create my own log-frame, but I'd like to use all available Fiddler functionalities.

It should be possible as the Title "-= Fiddler Event Log =-" is bold, too.

There is a `Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Log.LogFormat(string format, param object[] args)` function which [if I got that] wants to have the string to format and the commands how it should be formated. I cannot find anything useful to fill in that..

Any ideas, suggestions, trys or solutions?

greetings
TheChange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddler's Log tab uses a very simple formatting mechanism when interpreting the strings it receives in its `OnLogString` handler:

- Strings prefixed with an underscore ( `_` ) will render in an underlined font.
- Strings prefixed with an exclamation mark (`!`) will render in a bold font.
- Strings prefixed with a forward slash (`/`) render in an italic font.